# Prolog read_file_to_string/3

Tags: prolog

When I call the function read_file_to_string/3 in prolog, why am I getting this error:

```
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: read_file_to_string/3(DWIM could not correct goal).
```

I have tried calling it from a file that successfully compiles, but I get the same error.

Thank you.

Comment: Works for me in SWI-Prolog 7.3.20.

Comment: I have SWI-Prolog 6.6.4 on Ubuntu. The function isn't available for this version?

Comment: No, there are no strings at all in SWI-Prolog before 7. For Ubuntu, there is a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~swi-prolog/+archive/ubuntu/stable) if you don't want to compile from source.

Comment: There are a few issues here. If you want to commit to SWI-Prolog, please make sure to use a current version. The "devel" branch is in practice more stable than "stable" and you should use it. See [here](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/build/) if you want to know how to build. But if you are not decided which Prolog to use, you might want to stick to more standard/traditional ways of reading, writing, and treating "strings". This is beyond the scope of this question though.